# Wordpress SEO Features

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am using apache server for work with wordpress...In my application; retrieving some values from user created table and displaying it.
when click on a product description which shows the full details of that product.ie,
http://localhost/demotile/?productid=59961
this url am following for get the details.here how can i rewrite the url as **http://localhost/demotile/**............please help me

Comment: Please be more specific about what you want to do (original URL, rewritten URL), what kind of server environment you're on, why you can't use the built in method, and so on. In its current form, the question is not answerable.

Comment: Can you tell use more ? What exactly do you have, what exactly do you want *(with an example, ideally)* ? What have you tryied ? Do you get any specific kinf of error ?

Comment: @ajith what does that URL structure have to do with *Wordpress*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you login to wordpress dashboard, goto

```
Settings->Permalink
```

Change "Common settings" from default, select custom and input

```
/%postname%/
```

click "***Save Changes***"

if you get a message at the bottom of the page regarding your .htaccess file and not having permissions, you may have to create this file yourself.

open a new text file and copy/paste the info at the bottom of the screen, or copy this..

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

save this as "***.htacess***" {No filename - Just a Dot}
do this by saving the file with a name, then go to that file and hit F2 to rename, 
delete the filename just before the {dot} and change any file extention at the end:
ie: "yourfile.txt" should then become ".htaccess"
upload this into the root of your website hosting folder.

ie: public_html 
    or www 
    or htmldocs

As long as mod re-write is enabled on your host this will produce the following url
http://yourblog.com/your_post_title_or_product

If you are using a custom Wordpress plugin then you may have to check see which permalink structure is in use...

to do this use the..

```
if ( get_option('permalink_structure') != '' ) { echo 'permalinks enabled' }
```

you may have to look into using htaccess to generate your nice urls..

[perishablepress.com](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/16/comprehensive-htaccess-canonicalization-for-wordpress/)